How to inverse transform e^-x / (1-e^-1), 0<x<1 for importance sampling
Example 5.10 Statistical Computing with R (Rizzo) 
Estimate the following using importance sampling 
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-x}}{1+x^2}$$
$f_3(x)=\frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-1}}, 0<x<1$
u <- runif(m) #f3, inverse transform method
x <- - log(1 - u * (1 - exp(-1)))
fg <- g(x) / (exp(-x) / (1 - exp(-1)))
theta.hat <- mean(fg)
se <- sd(fg)

$u=\frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-1}}$ 
$u(1-e^{-1})=e^{-x}$ 
$\log\left(u(1-e^{-1})\right)=-x$ 
$-\log\left(u(1-e^{-1})\right)=x$ 
Where did $-\log\left(1 - u(1-e^{-1})\right)=x$ come from? And if U and (1-U) are supposed to be the same distribution, then why do I get the wrong output when I use x <- - log(u * (1 - exp(-1)))?

$\int_0^x\frac{e^{-t}}{1-e^{-1}}dt$ 
$\frac{1}{1-e^{-1}}\int_0^xe^{-t}dt$ 
$\frac{1}{1-e^{-1}}\left[e^{-t}(-1)\right]_0^x$ 
$\frac{1}{1-e^{-1}}\left[1-e^{-x}\right]=u$ 
$1-e^{-x}=u(1-e^{-1})$ 
$1-u(1-e^{-1})=e^{-x}$ 
$\log(1-u(1-e^{-1}))=-x$ 
$-\log(1-u(1-e^{-1}))=x$

How does this answer your question?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
